# What do the columns mean on the bounties tab?

Tags: support

Most of these seem self explanatory, however I'm confused about the last column. It doesn't seem consistent. I've searched for and read the documentation I've found on bounties both here on askubuntu meta and in the help but have found nothing that explains this column.

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: Bounties]

As you can see in this image of Mateo Bounties Earned the final column has a date and a name. What does the name indicate? You'll note that while more than 1/2 of them pictured have Mateo listed, three of them have other names. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? what columns? can you post a picture or give more description?

Comment: @Mateo Updated question with image. You might recognize this ;-D

Comment: It indicated the user with the last update to either the question and or the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Active** - Current bounties that you have in play, ones that you have started but not yet ended or awarded

**Offered** - bounties you have made to award other people

**Earned** - bounties that were given to your answer for being amazing! (note each of those answers in that list will have a answer from me with bounty points awarded ;))

The Date/Name column is the last thing that happened in the question/answer, could have been someone editing.

Comment: thank you, but I mean the date name column on earned bounties. The rest is self explanatory (at least to me)

Comment: oh, that is the last thing that happened in the question/answer, could have been someone editing - funny that some of them were last touched when I answered/edited my answer... click on the date and it should take you to the question or answer that was last touched - the should have a matching date, for being edited or answered

Comment: That's clear as glass. Thank you.

Comment: could you add your comment above to the answer? Thank you!